# Is there a way to make the wordpress title field text only or parse it in React?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

Im building a Next JS front end app, pulling in the posts via rest API from Wordpress. The problem I'm having is that Wordpress allows HTML in the title field, so when I access that data via rest api. The title comes with &amp; instead of & etc.

Example
Saved title in post:
Rock & Roll

Retrieved from API
Rock &amp; Roll

React parses html so it is rendered as a string, special characters and all. Is there a way to either just make the title field a text string? Or an easy way to parse it on the front end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look this up might help `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately wont work for me, as I pass the string down to other components, that render a string not HTML.

Comment: I did however just discover react-html-parser. That seems to do the job. Can parse the string first and then pass it down the props.